# KDE is not running script at start

Tags: bash, shell-script, fedora, kde

I created a .sh file to mount my drives via rclone.

The script has a shebang, correct permissions and works in terminal when I execute it directly.

Yet even if I add it to the autostart, login scripts in settings it does not get executed. While something like my browser does.

```
#!/bin/bash

rclone mount drive: ~/Documents/drive/ --vfs-cache-mode full &
```

Any ideas as to why kde is not running it properly?

Fedora 35 KDE spin.

Comment: Could you create a log of rclones output with `> /somedirectory/log.txt`?

Comment: Sadly I don't think I know how to do that. @mashuptwice